# Difference between using super pom of dependency between two project

Tags: java, maven, inheritance, dependencies, pom.xml

I have three project

> A B

and

> C

I want to create a **super project** contains the common technical features of the three project... so i want to know if i have to use the super project as a dependency or create a super pom inherited by the three project, to link the the technical base to the A, B and C projects.

```
<parent>    
        <groupId>C</groupId>    
         .    
         .     
</parent>
```

and add the super project as a dependency in each project pom file

Thank you.

Comment: I don't get at all what your asking. Do you want to have multiple parent? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: no just one parent, my question is :
what is the difference between adding the parent project as a dependency in the three project, and creating a super pom  that will be inherit by the three project 
(super pom vs dependency )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you by technical features mean some project configuration like `<pluginManagement>` or `<issueManagement>`, use parent pom and your configuration gets inherited.
If you talk about some libraries relevant for your code, use dependency. Project configuration will not be "inherited" via dependecies.